# c++ function can not call twice

Tags: c++, function

I have this code. From main function i twice call sportPrisevinners function and if it is first call of this function it works correctly and I recive correct result, but when i call it second time I recive incorrect result even I pass this function with same arguments. Please help me to solve this problem while it doesn`t make me crasy.

```
const char* countries[] = {"ru", "gb", "us", "uk", "ch", "de"};
const int countriesCount = 6;
const char* sports[] = {"runing", "swiming", "baseball", "football", "jumping", "kerling"};
const int sportsCount = 6;

enum {
    Empty = 0,
    Bronse,
    Silver,
    Gold
};

struct member {
    char sport[9];
    char country[3];
    int points;
    int medal;
};

struct members {
    member* list;
    int count;
};

string medalToStr(int medal)
{
    switch (medal) {
    case Gold:
        return "Gold";
    case Silver:
        return "Silver";
    case Bronse:
        return "Bronse";
    default:
        return "Empty";
    }
}

void printMembers(members &list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.count ; i++)
        cout << /*i << " " <<*/ medalToStr(list.list[i].medal) << " in "
             << list.list[i].sport << " with " << list.list[i].points
             << " from " << list.list[i].country << endl;
}

void generate()
{
    ofstream file("members.dat", ios::binary|ios::trunc);

    member temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < sportsCount ; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < countriesCount ; j++)
        {
            int count = rand()%5+5;
            for (int k = 0; k < count ; k++)
            {
                strcpy(&temp.sport[0], sports[i]);
                strcpy(&temp.country[0], countries[j]);
                temp.points = rand()%100;
                temp.medal = Empty;

                file.write((char*)&temp, sizeof(member));
            }
        }

    file.close();
}

members sportPrisevinners(const char* sport)
{
    //reading
    ifstream file("members.dat", ios::binary);
    member* loaded = new member[60];
    int pos = 0;
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        member temp;

        file.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(member));

        static bool reading = false;
        if (strncmp(&temp.sport[0], sport, strlen(sport))==0) {
            reading = true;
            loaded[pos++] = temp;
        } else if (reading) {
            break;
        }
    }
    file.close();

    //sorting
    int count = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos-1 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < pos ; j++)
            if (loaded[i].points<loaded[j].points)
            {
                member temp = loaded[i];
                loaded[i] = loaded[j];
                loaded[j] = temp;
            }

        if (i<count) {
            static int last = -1;

            if (loaded[i].points==last)
                count++;

            loaded[i].medal = count-i;
            last = loaded[i].points;
        } else break;
    }

    //returning
    members result;

    result.list = new member[count];
    memcpy(result.list, loaded, count*sizeof(member));
    /*for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        result.list[i] = loaded[i];*/
    result.count = count;

    delete[] loaded;

    return result;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
    srand(time(0));

    generate();

    members r = sportPrisevinners(sports[4]);
    printMembers(r);
    delete[] r.list;
    members l = sportPrisevinners(sports[5]);
    printMembers(l);
    delete[] l.list;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running it in something like valgrind - it sounds like you have undefined behaviour, of the sort that valgrind is very good at detecting.

Comment: I'd also try to make a minimum test case (say 1 or 2 members). That way you can give more information here, like what the expected output should be and what the actual output is. Try also to narrow down the place in the code where things go wrong by eliminating operations one by one.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` in your program? It will be much more appropriate and simple. You should avoid direct memory operations when you're writing in C++.

Comment: So the question is: what does the function do differently the first time it’s called from the second time it’s called?  Clue: `static` variables...

Comment: Brian Nixon, you are right! Thank you!

Comment: There are a lot of other bugs in this code though. For example, you don't check if `read` succeeds or fails. And you write data out to disk without actually serializing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's the static local variables in your function.  They won't have the same values on each call to the function, and this could affect the results.  The initialization of these variables is performed just once - the first time they come into scope - so each subsequent time the function is called, you pick up the values these variables had last time the function ran.